# Alphanumeric sorting in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Are there advanced sorting settings in excel that takes a string of data like "P9, P50, P8, P100," and arrange them in alphanumeric order? Doing it normally puts the order P100, P50, P8, P9, as it doesn't register P100 as being larger than P9?

Comment: It will...if you write each value in a consistent format such as, "P009, P050, P008, P100, ..."

Comment: Lets say I'm working with a dataset that isn't consistent, and already produced to be as I described. Is there a Text Function to pull out only the digits of a string?

Comment: Then I'd recommend that you try something like @Balinti 's suggestion below and parse the data using VBA on the way in; following that, you could use a custom number format/mask to always show a leading zero and then sorting is cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a auxiliary column with only the numeric data from the alphanumeric column (using excel functions like MID(text, start_num, num_chars)), and then sort the rows using this new column (yoy can hide this column).

Excel defaults options don't allow this kind of sorting, i'm afraid.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Thanks.

Are there any parameters to, say, extract characters based not on their position, but on what they contain (to extract the digits alone, regardless of their position). 

Thanks

Comment: @user1996971 unfortunately something like that is not available in a native Excel function; it would either require VBA or a (painful) setup which uses a helper column for each possible digit in a string. In your simplified example this might be possible but probably not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the data based on the comma and whatever you desire with text to columns.
Let’s say, if your data contains always P and the number at the beginning choose the  Data ribbon-> text to column -> delimited -> other and type there:

```
 , P
```

That will extract all of the rows… (For the 1st P just add  , with & command (concatenate) )
And then you will have only numbers in each column